# OpenCV: How to do phase shift the Fourier Transform?

Tags: opencv, fft, phase

I would like to create Hilbert Transform by doing phase shift 90 degree of Fourier Transform. I'm using OpenCV dft and idft for Fourier Transform and Inverse Fourier Transform (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html). But I dont know how to do phase shift. Please help.

Comment: Forget it, I figure out how to that by multiplying the result of FFT by a matrix with matrix h like this `h  = zeros(xr);

    if ((2*no2) == n) then  // n is even
        h([1,no2+1]) = 1;
        h(2:no2) = 2;
    else // n is odd
        h(1) = 1;
        h(2:(n+1)/2) = 2;
    end`

Comment: Instead giving the answer in a comment to your question, you could answer your own question and properly format the formulas. This would help future visitors of this site.